# Parsing xml data in java

Tags: java, xml

i have one requirement to get the data from the xml.

String res;

the data will be in the string res as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
  <id>QZhx_w1eEJ</id>
  <first-name>pratap</first-name>
  <last-name>murukutla</last-name>
</person>
```

i have to get the id and the first-name and last-name from this data and has to be stored in the variables id,first-name,last-name

how to access the xml to get those details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use JAXB (JSR-222) and do the following.  An implementation is included in Java SE 6.

**Demo**

```
package forum10520757;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<person><id>QZhx_w1eEJ</id><first-name>pratap</first-name><last-name>murukutla</last-name></person>");
        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(person.id);
        System.out.println(person.firstName);
        System.out.println(person.lastName);
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class Person {
        String id;

        @XmlElement(name="first-name")
        String firstName;

        @XmlElement(name="last-name")
        String lastName;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
QZhx_w1eEJ
pratap
murukutla
```

Comment: Thank you for your help..But this is simple task in one of my big java file..when i did the static class person it is showing the errors ..

Comment: @PratapMurukutla - The above code is copy and pasted from my Java editor.  Are you seeing exceptions in a modified version of it?

Comment: i do not know how to thank you...you have done this task for me....great help from this forum..

Answer (score 2):

You can start with:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = 
    new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody().getBytes("UTF-8"));
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
```

You can see an example in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/XMLDocumentinformationbyDOM.htm

Comment: Actually i am getting the xml result as response from one url and i can get the whole response in xml format...i need only the above 3 values...

Comment: the above xml data is only response.getBody()

Comment: To retrieve the three values ​​need to parse the XML and then move between the different nodes to obtain them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SAX or DOM parser that's built into Java.  Parse the String into a DOM tree, walk the tree, get your values.

http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html